# Sanitizing with mysqli::real_escape_string in Magento

Tags: mysql, database-update

I need to perform direct database operations(insert/update). In order to sanitize the insert values with mysqli::real_escape_string I need a current charset of the connection.

For database updates I am going to use `Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');` object.

Is it possible to acces sanitization function on this object or in any other way?

If not is it at least possible to get charset of the connection so that I can set it on mysql_real_escape_string function?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Magento uses PDO, not mysqli, so it does not make sense (and is not even possible) to use its functions. It's actually so abstracted away that even if you don't use the Magento ORM, you should use the underlying Zend_Db layer for arbitrary SQL queries, not PDO directly. The quote() method can be used to escape values, but I recommend using prepared statements instead wherever possible.

Example: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3575160/664108

Answer (score 1):

I am really sorry a simple question like this has gone unanswered!

Once you call `$resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');`
you have access to table names and other structure values.

calling an additional `$connect = $resource->getConnection('core_write'); //'core_read' for RO`

gives you the database connection.  This connection provides you with functions such as `->quote($string)` to escape data, `->insert($tablename, array(...))` to insert, `->fetchRow($querystring, $filterdata=array(...))` and many other operations. You will find that you will need both the database resource handle, and connection handle to look up table names and perform operations

The database connection is usually PDO, so there is no age-old-standard mysql connection to work with.

in the Magento code set: /lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php you will find one of the files that breaks down all the accessible functions through a database handle